# MOBILE SDK PAYPAL direct credit card payments - Outside UK, US

Tags: cordova, plugins, paypal, credit-card

I am using phonegap build to make an app. I have integrated a Paypal SDK Plugin but it only accepts credit cards from users in US or UK:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments

Does anyone know when this will be extended to countries outside UK/US like australia?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this last year and was on the phone with Paypal for the last two days. They said it is not working and even their card readers coupled with the app only works in the country where the account holder resides. I doubt this will ever be possible (most likely because they lose the control over where and who is making the payments outside these countries). I came across one option which is not ideal. You can use the web service from Paypal. If the payment goes through it will give a different URL than when it doesn't go through.